# Steps to replace a 10k ohm pot with a 10 ohm pot

Tags: pcb, potentiometer

I was about to build an all-in-one board for a retropie computer inside a gameboy advance sp shell, when I found this board that already was made and shared by someone else. I have a different potentiometer for the *audio circuit only* that I would like to use because it is the oem volume slider. The guy says everything else works and [here](https://github.com/granthaack/piboy?files=1) are the eagle files of the creators project:

[image: pot on the right side]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Not everyone here has Eagle installed. Can you please provide a schematic of the circuit in question (either a screenshot, or by using the EE.SE schematic capture)? Otherwise, people won't be encouraged to put time into answering your question.

Comment: I really doubt that a volume pot would be \$10\Omega\$.  If it has a "10" on it that refers to the resistance, it's almost certainly \$10\mathrm{k\Omega}\$.  So when you post the schematic, please post a picture of the pot you want to use, and maybe check its resistance with a VOM?

Comment: I will add a schematic of the volume control once I get home. The resistor on the diagram says 10k and my multimeter reading of the oem pot says 10 ohms.

Comment: You are probably measuring the wiper to the near end of the pot, or measuring with a speaker in parallel.

Comment: i have the figure uploaded and I will take the multimeter measurement again to be sure.

Comment: 10 ohms is about right for an L-PAD

Comment: I was wrong again, I tested known value resistors first to make my measurement of the pot accurate. The REAL readings are 25k ohms to 600 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

1. C11=10uF
2. 10uF*10KΩ=0.1s (Ideal)
3. C12=1uF
4. PAM8302 Zin=100k
5. C12*Zin=0.1s  ( ideal)

Don't use the 10Ω Pot. I will also excessively load and shift the LPF preceding it.  **It needs an Audio taper slider 10k pot.**

Comment: Could you please read the last comment on the question? The measured resistance is 25k ohm to 600 ohm.

Comment: OK then you are good to go

Answer (score -2):

If the calculations for the 10 ohms is right for the entire circuit and you only want to substitute the 10k pot on pcb with your 10 ohm one then you need to create  another specific package footprint which can be substituted in place of the original 10 k pot in Eagle. If there is already a footprint available for your 10ohm pot  them use that one. Later make sure there are no design errors left and then go on further for creating a Gerber file and finally print it. I hope this helped..